# Is there a PHP function for cutting a string into sections without cutting words?

Tags: php, string, function, string-length

I'm trying to find a php function that will take a string and a length number, and at that length in the string will cut it, but not if its in the middle of a word, only if its a space, and will check for the nearest space to do so.

It also would continuously do this and return the array of strings with however long the original string was (IE if the original string was about 240 in length and I wanted to cut around 80, the array would be 3 strings large).

I found a couple of functions but none that does that, and I'm having trouble creating my own.

Comment: You could include the function you have found, maybe some tweaking will help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`wordwrap`](http://php.net/wordwrap) function splits a string in lines of up to a given number of characters long.

It takes care of words and won't cut in the middle of a word (unless to tell it to).

You can use it and split the string by lines:

```
$string = wordwrap($string, 42);
$lines = explode("\n", $string);
```

Comment: PHP has really awesome built-in functions and language contrasts.

Comment: The language is not that bad when you know it

Answer (score 2):

You want [wordwrap()](http://us.php.net/wordwrap).

```
wordwrap (string $str, int $width = 75, string $break = "\n" , bool $cut = false)
```

The important thing is to make sure you have `$cut = false` so it doesn't slice words into two parts (which is the default setting).

Answer (score 1):

Use [`wordwrap()`](http://php.net/wordwrap) to do the wrapping, then you can [`explode()`](http://php.net/explode) the string on the linebreaks to get it in array format.